# Main difference in context between "eingeschätzt" and "abgeschätzt"

Tags: difference, german-to-english

What is the main difference in context between "eingeschätzt" and "abgeschätzt"?

From my point of view I used them with the meaning of "evaluated" or "estimated".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Germany we use the word

> eingeschätzt or einschätzen

to suppose a persons behaviour. For example:

> Ich habe ihn als vernünftiger eingeschätzt

means in english 'I thought he was more reasonable'.

> abgeschätzt or abschätzen

we use to estimate e.g. a time or a route.For exmaple:

> Ich glaube die Strecke ist ca. 500km lang.

means in english 'I think the route is approxiamtely 500km long'

Comment: you probably want to look into "abschätzig" as well.

Comment: Allerdings kann in einem Bericht eines Ingenieurs zu einer Bauwerkskontrolle auch stehen: "Die Brücke wird insgesamt als stabil eingeschätzt. Der Erhaltungszustand des Tragwerks wird als kritisch eingeschätzt." - Das Wort wird also nicht nur für menschlisches Verhalten verwendet.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Das ist richtig, jedoch glaube ich das er eher die allgemeine Form dieser Wörter meinte. Zumindest habe ich das so verstanden, da er keinen näheren Bezug auf irgendeine Fachrichtung erwähnt hat. Aber danke für die Korrektur, nun müsste es klar sein.

Answer (score 4):

*Einschätzen* is related to an opinion. It implies that it is either subjective or your personal opinion/estimate is demanded.

Examples:

> Wie schätzt du die aktuelle politische Lage ein?
>
> Wie schätzt du den Benzinverbrauch eines Sportwagens ein?
>
> Kannst du einschätzen, wie dein Bewerbungsgespräch lief?

*Abschätzen* is related to an estimate about a magnitude. It somehow implies a quick estimate that could be replaced by a more exact calculation or counting.

> Kannst du abschätzen, wie viel Benzin noch im Tank ist?
>
> Kannst du abschätzen, wiele Münzen in diesem Glas sind?
>
> Kannst du abschätzen, wie oft sich der Mars in einem Jahr um sich selbst dreht?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in addition to Ian's quite satisfying *opinion vs. quantity* thesis:

Ich meine, *einschätzen* wird typischerweise verwendet, wenn es um eine genauere, gründlichere, sorgfältigere, längerfristige Betrachtung geht:

<sup>[It seems to me that *einschätzen* is more in use when we think of a thorough, detailed, careful, meticulous and long-term assessment of something:]</sup>

> Der Erhaltungszustand des Tragwerks wird als kritisch eingeschätzt.
>
> Der Lehrer hatte den Schüler als verantwortungsbewusst eingeschätzt, doch er fand sich in ihm getäuscht: Der Chemiesaal sah aus wie nach einem Wirbelsturm.

Während "abschätzen" typischerweise eine eher oberflächliche, schnelle, grobe, vorläufige Form der Einschätzung beschreibt:

<sup>[*Whereas *abschätzen* would typically be used for a quick, rough, preliminary, effortless or superficial valuation:]</sup>

> Kannst du abschätzen, wie lang du dafür brauchst?
>
> Die beiden Streithähne schätzten sich kurz ab, dann gingen sie aufeinander los.

Comment: Answering an English question with a mix of German and English can quickly lead to a discussion that the owner of the question will no longer be able to follow - Please align your answer's language with the question language.

Comment: Well... okay... translation added. Hope it helps. (I am somewhat in doubt, as the sample sentences require good command of German anyway.)